# Vim in ubuntu isn't recognizing my environment variable

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, vim, cygwin

Sometimes I use Cygwin and sometimes I use Ubuntu. Since there are certain things in my `vimrc` that aren't recognized by Ubuntu, I made a shell variable called `$ENV_TYPE` that is manually set in my `.profile` to take care of discrepancies.

I have stuff like this in my vimrc:

```
if $ENV_TYPE == "cygwin"
    <some_command_here>
endif
```

When I run `echo $ENV_TYPE` on the command line in Ubuntu, it recognizes the variable. However, in vim, if I run the same command it doesn't output anything (which prevents some of the custom commands to not be recognized).

Note: this isn't a problem at all in Cygwin. Any ideas on how to fix this? A better way than using a manually set shell variable would also be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you `export ENV_TYPE` ?

Comment: Yes. It is set in my `.profile` with the following command `export ENV_TYPE="cygwin"` (it is manually set to the correct value depending on the whether I'm using Cygwin or Ubuntu)

Comment: In that case, are you sure that the `.profile` is being run?  Try running `env|grep ENV_TYPE` before you run `vi`.  In your `.vimrc` place an `echom` statement in your conditional.  By the way, you are using `.vimrc` and not just `vimrc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cygwin already exposes many Cygwin-specific environment variables for you so you don't really need to define your own. Use the command below to list them from your shell:

```
$ env
```

or this one to list them from Vim:

```
:!env
```

and pick one that's unique to Cygwin like `$OS` or `$PROGRAMFILES`:

```
if $OS == 'Windows_NT'
    " do cygwin stuff
endif
```

Another option could be to use the output of `uname`:

```
if substitute(system('uname'), '\n', '', '') =~ 'CYGWIN'
    " do cygwin stuff
endif
```

Here is a "universal" snippet:

```
if !exists('g:os')
    if has('win32') || has('win16')
        let g:os = 'Windows'
    else
        let g:os = substitute(system('uname'), '\n', '', '')
    endif
endif
```

that you use like this:

```
if g:os =~ 'Windows'
    " do Windows stuff
endif

if g:os =~ 'CYGWIN'
    " do Cygwin stuff
endif

if g:os =~ 'MINGW'
    " do Git Bash stuff
endif

if g:os =~ 'Darwin'
    " do Mac OS X stuff
endif

if g:os =~ 'Linux'
    " do Linux stuff
endif
```

Comment: How would I add/use the "universal snippet" in my `.profile` and `.bashrc`? They also used my shell variable `ENV_TYPE`

Comment: You wouldn't. This is a Vim answer to a Vim question.